# MVC с помощью Symfony

Tags: mvc, symfony

Есть проект в Symfony, который хочу переделать используя MVC. В проекте есть контроллеры и twig шаблоны, необходимо только прикрутить модель.**В какой директории проекта Symfony правильно создать файлы модели?** **Есть ли инструмент в Symfony позволяющий сделать это, вместо того, чтобы просто создавать эти файлы и подключать их к контроллерам?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию Symfony идет с ORM Doctrine 2, которая вместо Моделей использует Сущности (Entity). Сущности хранятся в каталоге Entity внутри бандла. Например, src/Acme/AppBundle/Entity/Product.php.

Более подробно написано в документации: 
[Databases and Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html)

Инструмент для их создания есть:

```
./bin/console generate:doctrine:entity
```

(на самом деле команд для работы с сущностями гораздо больше, весь список вы можете посмотреть набрав ./bin/console без параметров).

К контроллерам модели подключать не принято, обычно вся работа с моделями ведется в [сервисах](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html) и [репозиториях](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html), которые уже вызываются внутри контроллера.

Comment: А разве сущности это не часть модели? ;)

Comment: Нет. Модели и сущности - представление данных в виде объектов ООП. Основное отличие в том, что Модели могут взаимодействовать с базой данных (например вы всегда можете написать $model->save() и данные сохранятся в базу), а сущности работать с базой напрямую не умеют, они только представляют объект. Модели - часть паттерна ActiveRecord, а сущности - часть паттерна DataMapper. Здесь более подробно и с примерами - https://habrahabr.ru/post/198450/

Comment: Модель (предметной области) ничего общего не имеет с базой данных. Вообще. Сущности (как и репозитории/объекты-значения/агрегаты и прочее) - это термины именно модели предметной области. При этом, как именно отображаются сущности на базу (через ActiveRecord, DataMapper, TableGateway или что-то еще), это уже несколько другая история...

Comment: И вместо статеек на хабре надо читать классиков: PoEAA Фаулера и DDD эванса

Comment: В "статейке на хабре" как раз описаны шаблоны Фаулера.

Comment: Описаны поверхностно. Кроме того, если бы вы читали фаулера, то знали, что M в MVC - это как раз модель  предметной области, а вовсе не какая-то отсылка к DataMapper'у (или ActiveRecord'у)